# How to understand the uncertainty of quoted value of cosmic black body radiation?

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

Geiner's Quantum Mechanics - An Introduction quotes a alue of cosmic black body radiation, "$2.65 \pm 0.09 K$".  How to understand this uncertainty?  I have undergraduate mathematics degree and are familiar with basic probability theory and statistics but not physics.  When physicists give a value of some quantity in nature, and use an uncertainty, what does it exactly mean?

Comment: It's a [standard deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

Comment: Does it mean the same procedure of measurement is performed a number of times, and the obtained measured values are fitted to a normal distribution?  How is standard error and standard deviation usually differentiated?